# Integration in $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

I'm reading a text and find the following integral 
$\int_{S_{r}}f(X,Y,Z)d{S_{r}}$ 
where $f$ a function of three variables and $S_{r}=\partial B_{r}(x_{1},y_{1},z_{1})$ is the sphere of radius $r$. I'm not sure about the meaning of this integral, it is a triple integral, integral over $S_{r}$ and what is $dS_{r}$?

thank you.

Comment: I made a change to reflect that your surface is centered at a generic point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's actually a double integral over the surface of that sphere.

$$dS_r = r^2 \sin{\theta} \, d\theta\,d\phi$$

where $X=x_1 +r \sin{\theta} \cos{\phi}$, $Y=y_1+r \sin{\theta}\sin{\phi}$, and $Z=z_1+r \cos{\theta}$.  $\theta \in [0,\pi)$ and $\phi \in [0, 2 \pi)$.

The integral will then look like

$$r^2 \int_0^{2 \pi} d\phi \: \int_0^{\pi} d\theta \, \sin{\theta} \, f(x_1+r \sin{\theta} \cos{\phi}, y_1+ r \sin{\theta}\sin{\phi},z_1+ r \cos{\theta})$$